# Traversing the Clang AST using Python

Tags: python-3.x, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on using clang bingings python to travers c/c++ code into AST,how can I get a tree based AST structure?
Some pointers on where to start, tutorials or anything in this regard will be of great help!!!

I found a very useful work(If you want to check this out ,here is the link:https://www.chess.com/blog/lockijazz/using-python-to-traverse-and-modify-clang-s-ast-tree) and tried his code,unfortunately I didn't get a useful output.

```
function_calls = []           
function_declarations = []     
def traverse(node):

    for child in node.get_children():
        traverse(child)

    if node.type == clang.cindex.CursorKind.CALL_EXPR:
        function_calls.append(node)

    if node.type == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL:
        function_declarations.append(node)


    print 'Found %s [line=%s, col=%s]' % (node.displayname, node.location.line, node.location.column)

clang.cindex.Config.set_library_path("/Users/tomgong/Desktop/build/lib")
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()

tu = index.parse(sys.argv[1])

root = tu.cursor        
traverse(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) in order to do obtain the AST of C/C++ source code and explore the same using python.

You can find the API for exploring the AST in this [example](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/explore_ast.py) from the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone was having trouble still, I found that if you should be using `kind` instead of `type`

you can run `clang.cindex.CursorKind.get_all_kinds()` to retrieve all kinds and see that when using the `node.type` does not appear in any of them.

```py
function_calls = []           
function_declarations = []     
def traverse(node):

    for child in node.get_children():
        traverse(child)

    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.CALL_EXPR:
        function_calls.append(node)

    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL:
        function_declarations.append(node)


    print 'Found %s [line=%s, col=%s]' % (node.displayname, node.location.line, node.location.column)

clang.cindex.Config.set_library_path("/Users/tomgong/Desktop/build/lib")
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()

tu = index.parse(sys.argv[1])

root = tu.cursor        
traverse(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get a tree based AST structure?

The translation unit object's cursor (`tu.cursor`) is actually the start node of an AST. You might wanna use `clang` tool to visually analyze the tree. Maybe this will shed the light and give you the intuition on how to work with the tree.

`clang++ -cc1 -ast-dump test.cpp`

But basically, it boils down to getting children nodes of the main node (`tu.cursor`) and recursively traversing them, and getting to the nodes which are of interest to you.

You might wanna also check an article from Eli Benderski how to start working with the python binding:
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang#id9

> unfortunately I didn't get a useful output.

You might run into incomplete or wrong parsing, when you don't provide paths to  includes in the parsed file to libclang module. For example, if the source file you want to parse uses some of the QT includes, then you need to specify relevant include paths in the `parse()` call like in the example here:

```
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
tu = index.parse(src_file, args = [
     '-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/',
     '-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore'])
```

Also look for some comments in the libclang.cindex python module, they can help you. For example, I found the solution above by reading those comments.